# How to divide watersheds by iscochrones/travel times in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hydrology, watershed, isochrone, runoff

I need to divide my watershed by isochrones of equal travel time to the output, dividing my watershed to inter-isochronal areas in order to use the time-area method to calculate runoff time series, in other words I want to divide my catchment like this:[image: Example of an isochrone divided watershed and the resulting runoff time series]

Note that, I already have my concentration time values calculated, I just want to divide my watershed based on concentration time now.

Comment: Where do you have the time values? As attibutes on each line?